# Start WPF Application in Console Application

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to start WPF Application in Console mode?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<Application x:Class="WPF.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if (args.Length > 0)
  {
     switch (args[0].ToLower())
     {
       case "/g": RunApplication(); break;
     }
  }
}

private static void RunApplication()
{
    var application = new System.Windows.Application();

    application.Run(new App());
}
```

It will show Argument type 'WPF.app' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Windows.Window'.

Any solution to work around it?? 
Any different between

1.public partial class App : Application

2.public partial class App : Window

Comment: Why are you trying to do it that way?  Do you just want to have a console open on the side or is there a specific strategy behind this?

Comment: Because initially my application is a console application. I try to add new argument to start WPF application in my console application. @B.K.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could declare a Window and then start your app this way:

```
var application = new System.Windows.Application();
application.Run(new Window());
```

**EDIT:**

You seem a bit confused, so let me explain:

Say you have a program:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunApplication();
        }

        private static void RunApplication()
        {
            var application = new System.Windows.Application();
            application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

This will run a WPF application with no Window.

If, on the other hand, you pass a Window into application.Run(), you will get a WPF window.  App should not derive from Window, since it should derive from Application.

Application.Run method either takes no arguments or a Window.  It does not take Application.  Therefore, if you want to start a previously created Application, as you have over there, you should do something like this:

```
private static void RunApplication()
{
    var application = new App();
    application.Run();  // add Window if you want a window.
}
```

Lastly, if you want to just use `application.Run()` and not have to pass a specific Window, just declare a starting Window in your Application XAML using StartupUri:

```
<Application x:Class="WPF.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="SomeWindow.xaml">
</Application>
```

Comment: Yeah. For this it is able to run with public partial class App : Window.

but with public partial class App : Application, it will show Argument type 'WPF.app' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Windows.Window'.

Comment: So I wondering what is the different between extend Application & Window

Comment: @kingjia App should not derive from Window.  You should just have a Window to open.

Comment: BK are right. You only can use console or wpf. No way to open two types on the same process.

Comment: @IgorQuirino Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Ok, That's mean in order to start a WPF in console, we can only use Window instead of  Application? Am I correct?

Comment: @kingjia No, you can use both.  However, when you use Application.Run() method, it doesn't take another Application as argument.  It only takes Window or nothing.  If you pass nothing, it'll start, but nothing will show.  If you pass a Window, it'll start a Window.  However, if you declare a starting Window in your Application XAML, then it'll open a window that you've declared previously, if you use Application.Run() and pass nothing.  There are different scenarios.

Comment: @kingjia See another edit that shows one more method of opening a Window if you want one to be opened.

Comment: Important  - you MUST refernece to "PresentationFramework".

Comment: @user1223457 It's kind of a given, since you can't create a Window if you don't have the PresentationFramework.dll referenced.  That's where the System.Windows namespace comes from.

Comment: Not all the time. In my case I created a solutin with console application project and then added a wpf project. Took me some time to find all the neccesary dll's for it, so if anyone comes up with the same problem I'v written here the answer.

Comment: @user1223457 What I'm saying is that it's a given that you need that dll if you're planning on using the WPF framework.  If you're working with WPF, there's an assumption that you took the time to learn where the code comes from.