# How to print to the starting console of a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I have a WPF windowed application.
There is a new request to enable application's command line arguments.

1. Starting the app from command line (invoking `app.exe`) with no arguments, should start the GUI (as before)
2. Starting the app from a command line with GUI switch (e.g., `app.exe -gui`) should start the GUI (as before)
3. Starting the app from a command line with other switching (e.g., `app.exe -f a -b e`) should run the application in console mode (no window)

I have explored multiple posts such as [Start WPF Application in Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794377/start-wpf-application-in-console-application) (and similar), [No output to console from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application) and reviewed command line parsers utilities such as [Commandline Parser](https://github.com/j-maly/CommandLineParser).

When implementing all the above (see code below), in option 3, the application is running in a new console process (new cmd window), so wrong arguments or `--help` switch is opening a new window and immediatly it is being closed.

How can I make use of the console that i invoked the app from? So when the user opens a new cmd window and type `app.exe --help`, no new console process/window will be opened.

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static class ConsoleManager
{
    private const string Kernel32_DllName = "kernel32.dll";

    [DllImport(Kernel32_DllName)]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport(Kernel32_DllName)]
    private static extern bool FreeConsole();

    [DllImport(Kernel32_DllName)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport(Kernel32_DllName)]
    private static extern int GetConsoleOutputCP();

    public static bool HasConsole
    {
        get { return GetConsoleWindow() != IntPtr.Zero; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new console instance if the process is not attached to a console already.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Show()
    {
        //#if DEBUG
        if (!HasConsole)
        {
            AllocConsole();
            InvalidateOutAndError();
        }
        //#endif
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the process has a console attached to it, it will be detached and no longer visible. Writing to the System.Console is still possible, but no output will be shown.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Hide()
    {
        if (HasConsole)
        {
            SetOutAndErrorNull();
            FreeConsole();
        }
    }

    static void InvalidateOutAndError()
    {
        Type type = typeof(System.Console);

        System.Reflection.FieldInfo _out = type.GetField("_out",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        System.Reflection.FieldInfo _error = type.GetField("_error",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo _InitializeStdOutError = type.GetMethod("InitializeStdOutError",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        Debug.Assert(_out != null);
        Debug.Assert(_error != null);

        Debug.Assert(_InitializeStdOutError != null);

        _out.SetValue(null, null);
        _error.SetValue(null, null);

        _InitializeStdOutError.Invoke(null, new object[] { true });
    }

    static void SetOutAndErrorNull()
    {
        Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null);
        Console.SetError(TextWriter.Null);
    }
}
```

Code in my `Starter` class

```
 [STAThread]
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        // enable the console
        ConsoleManager.Show();

        parser.ExtractArgumentAttributes(CommandLineArguments);

        try
        {
            parser.ParseCommandLine(args);                

            if (parser.ParsingSucceeded)
            {
                CommandLineArguments.AnalyzeOptions();
                if (CommandLineArguments.OpenMode == CmdLineArguments.UI_TYPE.GUI)
                {
                    // GUI usage model                        
                    ConsoleManager.Hide();  // shutdown the console                        
                    App.Main();             // start up the UI
                }
                else // command line usage
                {
                    // do stuff without a GUI
                }
            }                
        }
        catch (CommandLineException parser_exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(parser_exception.Message);
            parser.ShowUsage();
        }
  }
```

Comment: I guess you should tear your app apart: 1 (or more) Core Libraries with all the Business, 1 WPF GUI App using the former, 1 Console App that either makes use of the Core Lib for operation without GUI or simply starts an instance of the GUI.

Comment: @Fildor: what is the difference between my above architecture and your proposal? It seems to me it is the same, isn't it?

Comment: You seem to cram all it into one Application. I am talking about 2 separate Applications and one (or several, depends on your architecture) Libs. You can have all of those in one Solution, but they would be different projects: Library, Console App and WPF App. That way you spare yourself from p/invoke and things will more likely actually work.

Comment: Then, if you want to start the GUI from Console, you can just use Process.Start from within your console App.

Comment: When it's in 'console' mode. What will your application do? It could be your logic should be in a windows service.